# sockets and file descriptor magic

Tags: sockets, fastcgi, lighttpd, flup

I have written a FCGI implementation that I use in a Webserver. I wanted to replace a simple setup with lighttpd.

And I found something odd.
When I try to spawn a Python-Flup server and then connect to it, it only works if I use a TCP Socket
([My Code](https://github.com/User65k/async-fcgi/blob/master/src/client/con_pool.rs#L168)).
However, in my existing setup with Flup and lighttpd it works also with Unix Domain Sockets.

(In FCGI, the Webserver gives the listening socket to the FCGI server as stdin).
So I took a look at Flups code (found it only local and [here](https://github.com/pquentin/flup-py3/blob/master/flup/server/fcgi_base.py#L1025)). It seems that only TCP is handled, so UDS should not work.
But with lighttpd it somehow does!

```
fastcgi.server = (
    "/heiz" =>
    (
       "python-fcgi" =>
       (
        "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi2.python.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/var/www/heiz/flup.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1
       )
    )
)
```

runs like:

```
sudo ss -lxp | grep /tmp/fastcgi2.python.sock 
u_str LISTEN 0      1024                    /tmp/fastcgi2.python.sock-0 4378053                                          * 0                                     users:(("flup.fcgi",pid=349092,fd=3),("flup.fcgi",pid=349092,fd=0))
```

But how? What am I missing?

I think the relevant parts are [here](https://github.com/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/blob/master/src/gw_backend.c#L1496) and [here](https://github.com/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/blob/master/src/gw_backend.c#L574)

Is it due to this [magic](https://github.com/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/blob/master/src/gw_backend.c#L705)?

I am confused

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd opens and binds to the configured listening socket `"socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi2.python.sock"`, whether TCP or UDS, and then makes that listening socket the `STDIN_FILENO` of your fastcgi backend when you configure `"bin-path" => "/var/www/heiz/flup.fcgi"`

My understanding is that Flup recognizes that there is a listening socket on `STDIN_FILENO` (a.k.a. `FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO`) and simply uses it.

Comment: You are right. However Flup just tries to use `STDIN_FILENO` as `AF_INET`. **That fails for UDS.** Yet somehow Flup ends up with working UDS as long as it comes from lighttpd.

Comment: Oh never mind - It apparently does not matter (at least to python) if a UDS is opened as AF_INET from a FD